# deploying helm chart using terraform on minikube gives chart: Still creating

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I'm trying to deploy a helm chart using terraform on minikube.  The deployment and pods all get deployed without a problem, however helm keeps complaining

```
example-chart: Still creating..[2m10s elapsed]
....
Error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

when I try `helm history` I see the following.

```
 Release <chartname> failed: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Trying `helm test chart --debug` shows me the following

```
NAME: <chart>
LAST DEPLOYED: Wed Jun 30 04:23:44 2021
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: failed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
null
```

I am not sure what condition its referring to.

When I try to install the chart with a simple helm command it works fine without a problem.  These are the contents of the file

main.tf

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = "~/.kube/config"
}    

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    config_path = "~/.kube/config"
  }
}

resource "helm_release" "example-chart" {
  name  = "example-chart"
  chart = "./config/k8s/example-chart"
}
```

My actual chart has a simple deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: brw-user-server-deployment
  labels:
    app: brw-user-server
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: brw-user-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: brw-user-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: brw-user-server
        image: {{ .Values.image.repository}}:1.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.image.grpcPort}}
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.image.httpPort}}
        readinessProbe:
          # tcpSocket:
          #   port: {{ .Values.image.httpPort}}
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 10
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: {{ .Values.image.httpPort}}
            scheme: HTTP
```

I thought it was something to do with the readiness probe but that also did not solve the issue.

Comment: after further investigation I found out that the issue was from the service, I have defined it as `type: LoadBalancer` and this was causing the issue.  However if I remove this then it worked.  Could it be because I'm on minikube ?  when I try `kubectl get services` I get externalIP pending.  I feel this is what could be cauing the issue.

Comment: Defining `type:LoadBalancer` indicates that you want to expose your Sevice outside of the cluster. Did you define another `type:` or was simply deleting the line? It could solve the issue that you were facing?
I've also found a simple guide about Helm chart deployment using Terraform Kubergrunt on Minikube in case you want to take a look for it 
https://registry.terraform.io/modules/gruntwork-io/helm/kubernetes/latest/examples/k8s-tiller-kubergrunt-minikube